# WSO2 ESB 7.1 or WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I was requested install WSO2 ESB 7.1.0 version but after get documentation about of the tool i realized that dont exist a tool named of this way, whoever asked me to do this was actually referring to WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is called Micro Integrator 7.1. The documentation is [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/overview/introduction/).